# What's the complete list of file name extensions used by Mathematica?

Tags: files-and-directories

What's the complete list of file name extensions used by Mathematica?  The ones I know are

Before V8

```
.m
.nb
.mt
```

After V9:

```
.cdf
```

Anything else (and their introduction time)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two that you left out were extension `.mx` (V4) and extension `.wl` (V10)

Comment: With the advent of `.wl`, is there a test file analogue to `.mt`?  Is it `.wlt`?

Comment: @qazwsx. I have not encountered .wlt files. In V10, a testing notebook template was introduced to support testing, but such files are just .nb files. However, such files might make testing files with a different extension unnecessary and perhaps deprecated.